# How do I parameterise in an interface and then specify generic type in implemented class

Tags: java, generics

I want to have an interface as :

```
public interface CarManager<T extends Car> {
    public T createCar(Map data);
    public T saveCar(T t);
}
```

so that I can do:

```
public class FiatManager<Fiat> implements CarManger {
    public Fiat createCar(Map data) {
         // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

for various cars that extend `Car`.

However, when I try, I get an error that I haven't implemented `createCar`

The exact error message is:

```
The class 'FiatManager' must be declared abstract or the method Car     createCar(Map data)' must be implemented.
```

Comment: Can you give the exact error message here.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to *implement* the interface:

```
public class FiatManager implements CarManager<Fiat>
```

Of course, you have to make sure that `Fiat extends Car`.

Also, (as [@Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo) correctly noted) note that `FiatManager` is not generic anymore, since it is already known as a one that's dealing with `Fiat`(s).

Comment: Note that `FiatManager` is not generic anymore, it already knows it is dealing with Fiats.

Answer (score 2):

For just `Fiat`s, then:

```
public class FiatManager implements CarManager<Fiat>
    public Fiat createCar(Map data) {
         // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

For all `Car`s:

```
public class FiatManager<T extends Car> implements CarManager<T>
    public T createCar(Map data) {
         // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your `FiatManager` class as:

```
public class FiatManager implements CarManager<Fiat>{
```

Then you need to implement both methods `createCar` and `saveCar`.

Of course, that is assuming you have a `Fiat` class extending or implementing `Car`.

Finally, watch out for the raw `Map` in your method parameters!